# Get the value of substring and then replace that with another string in js

Tags: javascript

I have a string

```
Date    Id    Number    Owner   GenderMaleFemale    Employment TypeExperiencedFresher   Issue TypeAutomation Code (script typos, File issues) Code (data model errors, utility errors)Platform Issues(db start up, network)Selectnull
```

I want to replace `GenderMaleFemale` with `Gender`, `Employment TypeExperiencedFresher` with `Employment Type` and replace `Issue TypeAutomation Code (script typos, File issues) Code (data model errors, utility errors)Platform Issues(db start up, network)Selectnull`    with  `Issue Type` in the string itself.

The values of Issue Type are never constant. I want this change to happen dynamically. How can I achieve this?

EDIT:
I tried doing

```
var string = "Date  Id    Number    Owner   GenderMaleFemale    Employment TypeExperiencedFresher   Issue TypeAutomation Code (script typos, File issues) Code (data model errors, utility errors)Platform Issues(db start up, network)Selectnull   "
string = string.replace("GenderMaleFemale", "Gender") 
console.log(string) // It replaces the GenderMaleFemale string as Gender. 
// But I don't know the value after Gender usually. Right now the options added are Male, Female if a new option gets added then I need to change the code. So I want replacement to be dynamic.
// I want to achieve something like
string = string.replace(/Gender/g, "Gender") // The output should be GenderMaleFemale word replaced as Gender.
```

Comment: Can you make a start on this, so readers know where to start helping you? This is a bit vague at the moment. It sounds like you need [String.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Comment: @halfer Thanks for the response, I m not getting how to replace the word containing GenderMaleFemale with Gender. For String.replace, if I pass Gender and replace the same as Gender no difference is seen. How can I achieve it?

Comment: replace will return the new string, it won't mutate the original string. Refer the MDN doc page mentioned for examples

Comment: It sounds like you have some code. Great! Please edit it into your question. Use the block formatting tool to preserve the indentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regex is the right idea. By defining a regex which looks for the characters `Gender`, followed by all non-whitespace characters you can identify any form of `GenderX` until a whitespace is met.

```
string = string.replace(/(\s)Gender[^\s]+/, '$1Gender');
```

I also included a whitespace character in front of `Gender` that is preserved in the replacement (`$1`).

Answer (score 0):

Replace Methid will return the new string so you have to init it to its self.

Try this :-

```
var WholeString =  'Date    Id    Number    Owner   GenderMaleFemale    Employment TypeExperiencedFresher   Issue TypeAutomation Code (script typos, File issues) Code (data model errors, utility errors)Platform Issues(db start up, network)Selectnull   ';

WholeString = WholeString.replace('GenderMaleFemale','Gender').replace('Employment TypeExperiencedFresher','Employment Type').replace('Issue TypeAutomation Code (script typos, File issues) Code (data model errors, utility errors)Platform Issues(db start up, network)Selectnull','Issue Type');

console.log(WholeString)
```